# CSS selector for an element if body has class

Tags: html, css, web

Im trying to apply a class to an element nested within a few elements of the body only if the body element has a certain class?

currently body has the class

```
    notie
```

I now have a div with another class

```
   stuffForNotIE
```

Im trying to achieve this by using the following selector

```
    body.notie > div.stuffForNotIE
```

this obviously isnt my real class names but Its a good example of what im trying to achieve?

Any ideas on the correct selector as the above is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`body.notie > div.stuffForNotIE` wont work because `>` means that you are selecting direct children of `<body>`, you need:

```
body.notie div.stuffForNotIE
```

so you can select ALL divs with class `.stuffForNotIE` even nested ones

Comment: Lovely! worked a treat. Turns out I had a problem in my browser detection aswell. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider the situation:

```
<body class="notie">
    <div class="forIEwhateveritis">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can target it using:

```
.notie .forIEwhateveritis {display: block;}
```

And others, you can use the `.notie` and target the elements. If the `body` doesn't contain the `.notie` class, the above rule will not be applied.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. A slight modification seen in @Pepo_rasta answer solves it. Thanks for your help

Comment: That's the same thing I gave.

Comment: same? despite you changed classess how about `<div class="notie"><span class="forIEwhateveritis"></span></div>`? such things leads to bugs in large projects

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Gave an example. Well... Whatever.

Comment: Praveen you ommited the body. and div. Thats the reason I accepted @Pepo_rasta as the answer

Comment: @user2976358 That's the worst explanation I can get from you. And in CSS, it is better you shouldn't give tag names. [Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS) and [Use HTML tag names, classes or IDs in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426499/use-html-tag-names-classes-or-ids-in-css) help you understand.